# 403 Forbidden When Posting HTML Tags

Tags: php, forms, wysiwyg

I have a form that I'm using the nicEdit WYSIWYG with the following buttons enabled:

- Bold
- Italicize
- Underline
- Unordered List

I can submit the form and process the an update to my SQL database when any one of those is used EXCEPT for the unordered list. When the text field makes use of the UL I receive a 403 Forbidden error from the server.

The form code looks is as follows:

```
<form action="actions.php?action=2" method="POST">
<p>How We Met Story</p>
<textarea name="area1" cols="50" id="area1"><?php echo html_entity_decode($row_rsHowWeMet['howWeMet']); ?></textarea>
<input name="websiteID" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_GET['websiteID'] ?>" />
<p><input id="partyEntry" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Save Changes" /></p>
</form>
```

And the code that processes the form is as follows:

```
$myMessage = htmlentities($_POST['area1']);

$sql2 = "UPDATE `tools_wedWebHowWeMet` SET `howWeMet` = '" . $myMessage . "' WHERE websiteID = '" . $_POST['websiteID'] . "'";

if (!mysql_query($sql2,$con))
{
echo "failed";
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Any ideas why this is happening? I've done some searching around and haven't found a solid answer. There was another thread on StackOverflow with a very similar issue but no answers. Thanks very much.

Comment: ***`Look at the error_log file`**, 403 is not an error orignated from a php file **at least not from your example as you dont use any header to impose 403 response**, check your files group and permission it is most likely your http server is using a different user to access the file or a folder with no permission. Aside from that your script is very very risk as it is you should consider reading about PDO or placeholders/verifying your data before insertion. http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html

Comment: For security reasons I would skip the built-in `<ul>` and `<li>` tags. Instead I would reformat it using custom tags, then convert those back when the data is read back in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that the difference in the POST array is really just whether or not it has a  tag in it (you should verify this by actually inspecting the POST and making sure that it's actually otherwise identical), I'm guessing this has to do with a software firewall (the 403 error is a tip-off that the problem is probably at the server level rather than the PHP level - though you may have a PHP file purposely sending 403 headers). Check to see if you have [ModSecurity](http://www.modsecurity.org/documentation/quick-examples.html) or something similar turned on. I suspect you may need to reconfigure your server's firewall, as they can be configured to reject specific tags, etc (specifically, check out `SecFilter` settings)

Comment: @inhan I cannot really use custom tags because the "processing" page won't even load before giving me the 403 error. If it was a matter of inserting into the SQL DB I would most likely do something like that.

Comment: @MingMing think that comment was supposed to be in response to inhan's note above. Modifying the firewall settings will allow you to use the tags without converting the data (assuming I'm right)

Comment: You're right that comment was supposed to be above! Ben You're probably right though. I've been reading more into the issue and everyone who's run into this problem seems to be pointed in the mod_security direction. Assuming when you say "firewall" you mean software firewall aka mod_security, then yes you're right. Now I just have to get that modified...which probably means putting in a ticket with the hosting company.