# Sending facebook image path via ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, image

I am trying to send an image path to my server so that I can copy that image from facebook to my own server. But I am not able to send the image path. It gives me `403 Forbidden` error.

```
$.ajax({
            url:'http://url.com/albums/copyFromFacebook',
            data: { p : path , id : ids},
            type : 'POST',
            success:function(e)
            {
                alert(e);
            }
        });
```

The `p` in the `data` field should contain the path. Whenever I remove this parameter the ajax request works fine. But whenever I put this parameter I get a 403 Forbidden error.

Comment: have you tried urlencoding the path?

Comment: I tried urlencoding but same error

Answer (score 1):

A quick [google search](https://www.google.gr/search?q=php%20403%20forbidden%20when%20posting%20url) returns a few stackoverflow questions similar to yours

[403 Forbidden on form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4341548/168097)

[403 Forbidden When Posting HTML Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10809022/168097)

[Error 403 triggered when posting URL's via form with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14250412/168097)

With all of them suggesting [ModSecurity](http://www.modsecurity.org/documentation/quick-examples.html) as a possible culprit